# How to check the last chunk?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i'm using the chunk method `chunk` to get big data but i need to know the last chunk, because i'm punting the data in file, and at the last chunk i don't want to add something to the file , so i need to know the last chunk

```
DB::table('users')->chunk(100, function($users)
{
    //how to know if it's the last chunk or not ?
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

is their a way to know the last chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could do it manually by a counter like this:

```
//get total number of users
$noOfUsers = DB::table('users')->count();

$chunk = 100;

$iterations = ceil($noOfUsers/$chunk);//this many times the loop should go on

//start a counter with 1 and increase it every time
$counter = 1;

DB::table('users')->chunk($chunk, function($users) use (&$counter, $iterations)
{
    //when counter gets equal to iterations, thats your last chunk
    if ($counter === $iterations) {
       //this is the last chunk
    }

    foreach ($users as $user) {
       //
    }
    $counter++;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but i was looking for some bullied in method to do this

Comment: I doubt there is one

Comment: I used this but I get ```You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function.```.

Comment: @Vagabond that is related to your own script you might have put in, you can open a new stackoverflow question for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this documentation about chunks in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk